# CollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(title) does not work after changing appbarLayout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want to load a fragment with the collapsed collapsingToolbar (i.e. in its non-expanded form). When I set the title of the collapsingToolbar without altering the appbarLayout layout parameters, the title is set properly and I can see the title.

The problem is, I also need to alter the appBarLayout layout parameters to prevent the collapsingToolbar from expanding (i.e. I want it to look and behave like a regular non-collapsing toolbar for this particular fragment). However, doing so makes the title no longer appear.

**What I've tried:**
I've tried solutions listed at these pages to no avail:

- [CollapsingToolbarLayout setTitle() not working anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073812/collapsingtoolbarlayout-settitle-not-working-anymore)
- [CollapsingToolbarLayout setTitle() does not update unless collapsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682548/collapsingtoolbarlayout-settitle-does-not-update-unless-collapsed)
- `collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(true);` doesn't seem to have any effect

**MainActivity.java**
I believe I have isolated the problem to these lines, but I am not sure how to solve it.

```java
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("All Recent"); // works
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true); // works

// However, after adding the following lines, the above no longer works and the title does not appear in the toolbar
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
appBarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:title="@string/drawer_item_locate_events" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_fragments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_a_photo"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Title no longer shows after altering appbarLayout's parameters

[image: Title no longer shows after altering appbarLayout's parameters]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue using the following answer provided by @DanielPersson at [how to pin title in Toolbar inside CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403357/how-to-pin-title-in-toolbar-inside-collapsingtoolbarlayout):

```java
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);
toolbar.setTitle("My Title");
```

By calling `setTitleEnabled(false);`, the title appeared in the toolbar.

Comment: It only works for me if I have the Toolbar.app:title set to a non empty value via xml first. After that this solution works...

Answer (score 4):

Just add this line of code to the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` tag in your xml layout.

```
app:title="Title You Want"
```

It works If you want to Change the collapsingToolbarLayout title.

Answer (score 3):

It is the same as setting title in a normal toolbar.

In your xml layout file for collapsing toolbar, inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` you'll have a normal toolbar (`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`) for which you should set an id (`android:id="@+id/toolbar"`). Find this toolbar using the id in your java class and set the title.

```
  mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
  getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.home);
```

Answer (score -7):

Calling

```
this.setTitle("Whatever you want");
```

from `onCreate` of your activity should solve your problem.

Comment: Doesn't works, we need setTitle of CollapsingToolbarLayout